# Скачать документ по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, fetch

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйстa, почему в первом варианте не скачивается файл, если в fetch передать данные?

Вариант 1:

```
   const handleSubmit = () => {
           clearingToBestDownloadRequest.fetchData(dataDownload!)
               .then( (response: any) => {
                   response?.blob().then((blob: any, headers: any) => {
                       const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                       let alink = document.createElement('a');
                       alink.href = fileURL;
                       alink.download = "Clearings.ikm";
                       alink.click();
                   }
               )
               .catch((reason:any) => <>{reason}</>)
           })
   };
```

А в этом варианте все работает..
Вариант 2:

```
   const handleSubmit = () => {
       fetch("https://random/path").then((response: any) => {
               response?.blob().then((blob: any) => {
                       const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                       let alink = document.createElement('a');
                       alink.href = fileURL;
                       alink.download = "aaaaa.ikm"
                       alink.click();
                   }
               )
                   .catch((reason:any) => <>{reason}</>)
           })
   };
```

Буду благодарна любой подсказке, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Простите, основная проблема была в ендпоинте. А также моя ошибка в headers -то что response всегда возвращает только 1 аргумент, т.е. если надо было доставать headers, то через response - response.headers.get()